# How to set logging.file and logging.file.max-size together in application.yml

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to set logging.file and logging.file.max-size together in application.yml

In application.properties I can write:

```
logging.file=file.log
logging.file.max-size=1MB
```

But if I write in application.yml

```
logging:
 file: file.log
  max-size: 1MB
```

my application fails to start:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load property source from location 'classpath:/application.yml'
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:556)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadForFileExtension(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:502)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:469)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.lambda$null$6(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:450)
```

Answer (score 0):

Should set by following way:

```
logging:
    file: file.log
        max-size: 1MB
```

Comment: So make sure `application.yml` is in /src/main/resources

Answer (score 0):

I've found a discussion on this problem and an answer [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/12510)

There's an advice to write it as:

```
logging.file: file.log
logging:
 file:
  max-size: 1MB
```